# Loading table in Databricks job converts all columns to lowercase

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, pyspark-schema

I have a SQL view stored in Databricks as a table and all of the columns are capitalised. When I load the table in a Databricks job using spark.table(<<table_name>>), all of the columns are converted to lowercase which causes my code to crash. However, when I load the table the same way in a simple notebook, the column names remain capitalised and are NOT turned to lowercase.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? It is strange because it is only happening in the job.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by changing the Runtime Version of the cluster used in the Databricks Job. Seems like that specific Runtime Version was automatically converting all column names to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you to check the whole process once again. I have repro’d it in our environment, and I ***didn’t get any lowercase columns*** in my result.

I have created an SQL view `names_view` in databricks for my repro and this is my **Notebook run** named `forview`.

[image]

**Databricks Job run:**

[image]

I suggest you try with `spark.sql()` to ***load the SQL view*** and check like below.

```
view_df=spark.sql("select * from names_view")
```

[image]

If you didn’t succeed, try to do it in another cluster or another databricks workspace and check if possible.

If the issue still persists, please reach out to [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) or can raise a [Github Issue](https://github.com/features/issues).

Comment: Thank you Rakesh! We actually managed to find the issue and it was the Cluster Runtime we were using. For some reason, the Cluster Runtime used on the job was automatically converting all column names to lowercase. We changed the runtime and problem solved!